# Custom ajax request button

Tags: asp.net, button, user-controls, ext.net

I searched lots of pages but coulnt find an appropriate example.Is it diffucult write our custom button which make a ajax reguest to the  server.I know I can do it jquery an ajax call but how can I do a custom button make ajax request and hadle the parameters sent by the client.
for instance like ext.net button.they have 2 different ajax button handler ,one is called directmethot and directevent.

Comment: Do a search on 'usercontrol button click event' you will get a load of pages that should point you in the right direction... any other help it is best to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the official Ext.NET examples of [DirectEvevents](http://examples.ext.net/#/search/directevents) and [DirectMethods](http://examples.ext.net/#/search/directmethods) is the best thing to start.